# Iterating through different-sized grids to play audio for Conway's Game of Life

Tags: javascript, loops, web-audio-api

So I have an iteration question for my version of [Conway's Game of Life](http://pmav.eu/stuff/javascript-game-of-life-v3.1.1/) (That is not my code, just an example of the game logic). So basically there are multiple sizes of the game board, going from 32(W)X16(H), and increasing in powers of 2 to 1024(W)X512(H). I am creating an audio version, so that whenever a cell becomes alive, web audio plays an oscillator note for a brief duration. The frequency and gain of that note depends on where on the board the audio is located. I have 32 frequency nodes and 16 gain nodes, so the cell at the top most right of the board would play the note at the highest frequency and the largest gain (.8). My problem comes when the board sizes increases, such as 64X32. I am having trouble figuring out the logic of how to determine which note and gain to use, as the cells in position 0 and 1 (left to right from the bottom) would have the same frequency, as would the cells in position 0 and 1 (bottom to top from the left corner) be having the same gain. Here is the code for my portion where I am having problems:

```
function updateGame()
{
// GO THROUGH THE UPDATE GRID AND USE IT TO CHANGE THE RENDER GRID
for (var i = 0; i < gridHeight; i++)
    {
        for (var j = 0; j < gridWidth; j++)
            {
                // HOW MANY NEIGHBORS DOES THIS CELL HAVE?
                var numLivingNeighbors = calcLivingNeighbors(i, j);

                // CALCULATE THE ARRAY INDEX OF THIS CELL
                // AND GET ITS CURRENT STATE
                var index = (i * gridWidth) + j;
                var testCell = updateGrid[index];

                // CASES
                // 1) IT'S ALIVE
                if (testCell === LIVE_CELL)
                    {
                        if (gridWidth == 32)
 {
 if (gainHeight == 0)
 {
  gainNode[0].gain.value = .05;
  osc[i].connect(gainNode[0]);
  gainNode[0].connect(context.destination);
 }
 else {
  gainNode[j].gain.value = .05 * j; 
  osc[i].connect(gainNode[j]);
  gainNode[j].connect(context.destination);
      }
    osc[i].start(context.currrentTime);

if (context.currentTime == .5)
{
gainNode[0].gain.value = 0;
osc[i].connect(gainNode[0]);
gainNode[0].connect(context.destination);
}   

}
else if (gridWidth == 64) //issues begin here
{
if (gainHeight == 0 && (j == 0 || j == 1))
{

}
else
{

}
}
else if (gridWidth == 128)
{

}
else if (gridWidth == 256)
{

}
else if (gridWidth == 512)
{

}
else {

}
                        // 1a FEWER THAN 2 LIVING NEIGHBORS
                        if (numLivingNeighbors < 2)
                            {
                                // IT DIES FROM UNDER-POPULATION
                                renderGrid[index] = DEAD_CELL;
                            }
                        // 1b MORE THAN 3 LIVING NEIGHBORS
                        else if (numLivingNeighbors > 3)
                            {
                                // IT DIES FROM OVERCROWDING
                                renderGrid[index] = DEAD_CELL;
                            }
                        // 1c 2 OR 3 LIVING NEIGHBORS, WE DO NOTHING
                        else
                            {
                                renderGrid[index] = LIVE_CELL;
                            }
                    }
                // 2) IT'S DEAD
               else if (numLivingNeighbors === 3)
                   {
                       renderGrid[index] = LIVE_CELL;
                   }                    
               else
                   {
                       renderGrid[index] = DEAD_CELL;
                   }
            }
    } 
 }
```

I haven't actually implemented the audio portion of the code yet, as I wanted to make sure I had the correct logic going forward before I started messing with web audio. I have an array filled with 32 oscillator nodes, and an array filled with 16 gain nodes valued from .05 to .8. Thanks for the help, and hopefully this made sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be as simple as dividing the coordinate by how much you are scaled up past 32x16. For a width of 64, you'd use `Math.floor(i/2)` instead of just `i`. Sorry if this was obvious and I missed the point of the question...

Comment: nope that was the answer I was hoping for. Just wasn't sure how to perform it syntactically. Thanks for the quick response!